# Unable to find the same solution on CPLEX and MATLAB for a quadratic program

Tags: matlab, optimization, cplex, docplex, quadratic-programming

I'm trying to solve the following quadratic problem with MATLAB (using quadprog function) and CPLEX. The problem is that MATLAB and CPLEX provided feasible solutions but both solutions didn't match. In fact, CPLEX claims that the obtained solution is optimal while the solution obtained with MATLAB is better in terms of objective.

```
Minimize obj= 0.5*(1100*x^2 + 509*y^2 + 33*z^2 + 1060*x*y + 252*y*z + 260*z*x)- 60*x- 36*y - 11*z

Subject to:
-x-y+z <= 10
-x+y-z <= 10
-x+y+z <= 10
x-y-z <= 10
x-y+z <= 10
x+y-z <= 10
x+y+z <= 10
-x-y-z <= 10
x,y and z are real numbers.

In matlab, I got: obj=-3, x=0.0436, y=-0.2670, z=1.1830
In CPLEX, I got: obj=-2.07, x=0.028, y=0.000, z=0.222
```

I don't understand why.

I tried to solve the problem with MATLAB and CPLEX but the solutions didn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which cplex version have you tried ?

I wrote

```
dvar float x;
dvar float y;
dvar float z;

minimize 0.5*(1100*x^2 + 509*y^2 + 33*z^2 + 1060*x*y + 252*y*z + 260*z*x)- 60*x- 36*y - 11*z;

subject to
{
-x-y+z <= 10;
-x+y-z <= 10;
-x+y+z <= 10;
x-y-z <= 10;
x-y+z <= 10;
x+y-z <= 10;
x+y+z <= 10;
-x-y-z <= 10;
}
```

in OPL CPLEX and got obj -3

```
x = 0.043662;
y = -0.26761;
z = 1.1831;
```

and with docplex python I also get the same

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='quad')

x=mdl.continuous_var(name='x',lb=-10,ub=10)
y=mdl.continuous_var(name='y',lb=-10,ub=10)
z=mdl.continuous_var(name='z',lb=-10,ub=10)



mdl.minimize(0.5*(1100*x*x + 509*y*y + 33*z*z + 1060*x*y + 252*y*z + 260*z*x)- 60*x- 36*y - 11*z)


mdl.add(-x-y+z <= 10)
mdl.add(-x+y-z <= 10)
mdl.add(-x+y+z <= 10)
mdl.add(x-y-z <= 10)
mdl.add(x-y+z <= 10)
mdl.add(x+y-z <= 10)
mdl.add(x+y+z <= 10)
mdl.add(-x-y-z <= 10)

mdl.solve(log_output=True,)

decisionVars=[x,y,z]
for v in decisionVars:
    print(v.name," = ",v.solution_value)

print(mdl.objective_value)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used docplex on python and the CPLEX version is
 Version identifier: 20.1.0.1 | 2021-12-07 | 9dfdf6686. What version of CPLEX did you use?

Comment: I used CPLEX 22.1